# jQuery .val() passes null to server side

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, hibernate, servlets

when I populate my input field with an onClick event with jQuery and inserting that clicked value into the input upon sending the form to the database I get the next error :

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ws.ApplicationConfig] in
>   context with path [/CRUDAngularJS_Server] threw exception
>   org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a
>   null or transient value: entities.Product.startdate

this is the input setup

```
            <div id="bookmenu">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Booking Information</legend>
    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="product.name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="product.email"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Phone</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="product.phone"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Service</td>
            <!-- ng-options="product.service.text for product.service in objectList track by product.service.Main Haircut"  - returns null -->
            <td><select type="text" ng-model="product.service" id="serviceSelect">
                <option value="Man Haircut">Man Haircut</option>
                <option value="Woman Haircut">Woman Haircut</option>
                <option value="Hair Dye">Hair Dye</option>
                <option value="Abu Agela">Abu Agela</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Start date</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="product.startdate" id="startdateID" readonly></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>End date</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="product.enddate" id="enddateID"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Book" ng-click="add()">
```

and this is the jquery script surrounded with setTimeout to see if I refresh the selection after fetching it will actually apply it to the field.

the complete onClick function

```
select: function(start, end) {
                // Booking Form Toggle
                if ($('#bookmenu').css('display') === "none") {
                $('#bookmenu').show();}

                // Fetching data from click event to booking form
                var startString = start;
                startString = new Date(startString).toUTCString();
                startString = startString.split(' ').slice(0, 5).join(' ');

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#startdateID").val(String(startString));
                    console.log($("#startdateID").val());
                                        }, 500);

                // Constructing the end date based on start date + service.duration

            },
```

> console.log($("#startdateID").val());

returns the appropriate selection.

if I copy-paste the data that populated in that field and submit it works fine but I want that field to be readonly.

Comment: It would help to see more code; without context it's not at all clear what the point is of that `setTimeout()` and how it relates to the form being POSTed.

Comment: added some more of the code, if anything else is needed lmk.

Comment: FYI: Form fields only post if they have a `name`.

Comment: edited : its not a part of a form its inside a div. added the entire html code.

Comment: I appreciate down voting and suggesting ways to improve ones question, but once its improved you might remove the down votes and maybe take them under consideration.